# how to increase the size of image using media queries

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, media-queries

I want to increase the image size whenever the window size decreases and I used the media queries for that. whenever the window size is 423 then the image size increases. so I tried using media queries but it didn't apply to that tag. how  to increase the size? this is my HTML and CSS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    @media screen and (max-width:768px ) and (min-width: 320px)
      {
             .samyata {
              width:100px;
              height:auto;
             }

          }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid text-center" style="background-color:#F2F2F2"><br>
   <h3 style="text-align:left;margin-left:12%;font-family: 'Raleway';"> Explore Samyata</h3> <br><br>

   <div class="row"  id = "first" style="margin-left:7%" >
     <div class="col-sm-6">
     <img src="Assets/img/sam.png" class = "samyata"
      hspace="30" style="width:28%;height:40%;float:left;">

       <h5 style="font-family: 'Fira Sans Condensed';text-align: left;">
         Get it the way you want </h5>
         <p class="text" style="text-align:left;font-size:13px;font-family: 'Dosis';">
         A new and effecient retail commerce platform
         and ecosystem to bring stores, shoppers and
         personal shoppers together in a geographically 
         specific, simple buying and selling experience.
       </p> 
       <a href = "#" class = "text3" 
       style="color: #2F80ED;text-align:left;font-family: 'Ubuntu';margin-right:63%;"> Explore Samayata </a>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
     <img src="Assets/img/vahaka.png" hspace = "30" class = "vahaka" style="width:28%;height:40%;float:left;"> 

        <h5 style="font-family: 'Fira Sans Condensed';text-align: left">
         Make money as a personal shopper </h5>
         <p class="text" style="text-align:left;font-size: 13px;font-family: 'Dosis'">
         Deliver shopper purchases. 
         Be your own boss. Do it when you want.
         Get paid right away.
       </p> 
       <a href = "#" class ="text3"
       style="color: #2F80ED;text-align:left;font-family: 'Ubuntu';margin-right:70%"> Explore Vahaka </a>

    </div>

     </div><br><br>
     <div class = "row" style="margin-left:7%">
    <div class="col-sm-6" >
     <img src="Assets/img/gananam.png"  hspace = "30"  style="width:28%;height:40%;float:left;">
            <h5 style="font-family: 'Fira Sans Condensed';text-align: left;">
        Attract shoppers to your stores </h5>
         <p  class="text" style="text-align:left;font-size:13px;font-family: 'Dosis'">
             Partner with Samyata Stores 
             for a new way to make money, 
             reach new customers and deliver 
             products to your customers.</p>
       <a href = "#" class = "text3"  
       style="color: #2F80ED;text-align:left;font-family: 'Ubuntu';
       margin-right: 63%"> Explore Gananam </a><br><br><br>


    </div>
   </div><br>
   </div>

</body>
```

How to apply that? please help me out from this problem. I want all the images and text side by side when the window size is decreases and increase but when i decreases i comes same part of the text under the image. i want all the text on the same side of image.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The img with class="samyata" has its style inline (i.e. in a style attribute). This will always override the style in the stylesheet.

Solution: take the style out of the attribute and put it in the stylesheet, above the media query.

Your other problem, the text wrapping around below the images, can be solved by putting the text in a block of its own and giving that a left margin.

```css
.samyata, .vahaka, .gananam {
  width: 28%;
  height: 40%;
  float:left;
}

.row {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.block {
  margin-left:37%;
}

.col-sm-6 h5 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-family: 'Fira Sans Condensed';
  text-align: left;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 320px) {
  .samyata, .vahaka, .gananam {
    width: 100px;
    height: auto;
  }

  .block {
    margin-left:130px;
  }
}

</style>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid text-center" style="background-color:#F2F2F2"><br>
  <h3 style="text-align:left;margin-left:12%;font-family: 'Raleway';"> Explore Samyata</h3> <br><br>

  <div class="row" id="first" style="margin-left:7%">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rblbG.jpg" class="samyata">
      <div class="block">
        <h5> Get it the way you want </h5>
        <p class="text" style="text-align:left;font-size:13px;font-family: 'Dosis';">
           A new and effecient retail commerce platform and ecosystem to bring stores, shoppers and personal shoppers together in a geographically specific, simple buying and selling experience.
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="text3" style="color: #2F80ED;text-align:left;font-family: 'Ubuntu';margin-right:63%;"> Explore Samayata </a>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row" style="margin-left:7%">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3atj.jpg" class="vahaka">
      <div class="block">
        <h5> Make money as a personal shopper </h5>
        <p class="text" style="text-align:left;font-size: 13px;font-family: 'Dosis'">
           Deliver shopper purchases. Be your own boss. Do it when you want. Get paid right away.
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="text3" style="color: #2F80ED;text-align:left;font-family: 'Ubuntu';margin-right:70%"> Explore Vahaka </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row" style="margin-left:7%">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUvgC.jpg" class="gananam">
      <div class="block">
        <h5> Attract shoppers to your stores </h5>
        <p class="text" style="text-align:left;font-size:13px;font-family: 'Dosis'">
           Partner with Samyata Stores for a new way to make money, reach new customers and deliver products to your customers.</p>
        <a href="#" class="text3" style="color: #2F80ED;text-align:left;font-family: 'Ubuntu';
           margin-right: 63%"> Explore Gananam </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, don't use `hspace`. It is deprecated and has compatibility problems. Use margins instead.

Edit: I made some changes, but I'm not sure it looks the way you want now. So consider this a work in progress.

Comment: _The img with class="samyata" has its style inline (i.e. in a style attribute). This will always override the style in the stylesheet._ For completeness sake: A `!important` style from a stylesheet does override a regular inline style. A `!important` inline style will override a `!important` stylesheet style tho.

Comment: @FabianSchöner Sure, but don't forget that `!important` is an absolutely last-resort, tried-everything-else trick that destroys the normal cascade order and that causes more problems than it solves.

Comment: @vijju I changed the code to turn it into two columns now, but I found I don't know how large you want the images to be. The media query makes the images 100px wide on 320 to 768 screens, and 28% on both wider and narrower  screens, can that be right?